# The query in stored procedure returning null instead of a Integer

Tags: mysql

I am using a concatenate function to run a subquery in a stored procedure. This query is supposed to return a number but its returning NULL. Your help is appreciated.

```
set @Sl =Concat('select sum(etl_insert_rows) into @Times 
from Table1
where etl_job_id in
(SELECT etl_job_id
FROM Table2 where etl_target_table="',@TabName,'")');

Prepare stmt from @Sl; 

Execute stmt;
```

Comment: I am using the @Times for further processing in stored procedure

Comment: You mean to say query should return number of rows Inserted right?

Comment: No, etl_insert_rows is a column, it should return the sum for this column data.